# When $|x|$ is defined as $\sqrt{x^2}$, does the $\;\sqrt{\;}\;$ denote the principal square root?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

The absolute value of $|x|$ is defined to be equal to $\sqrt{x^2}$ in my calculus book. And a small question occurs:

> Does the $\;\sqrt{\;}\;$ here denote the principal square root?

Because it has never been quite pointed out, and while I intuitively believe it does, I just wouldn't like to make the leap without listening the more professional.

Another question is of a proof the book provides. I won't go into the proof itself, but somewhere near the end we obtain
$$\sin^2\theta < \theta^2$$
From this the author infers the inequality
$$-\theta < \sin\theta < \theta$$
and I cannot seem to connect how that follows. I see how $\sin\theta < \theta$ I just don't see how it's greater than $–\theta$. Thank you in advance.

Comment: $\sqrt{x^2}$ is actually one possibility to define $|x|$ because by convention , always the non-negative square-root is meant. But usually it is defined by cases ($x$ for $x\ge 0$ and $-x$ for $x<0$)

Comment: We also have $(\sqrt{x})^2=x$ , but this is only defined for $x\ge 0$.. The inequality in the second part does not hold for $\theta=0$

Comment: For what its worth, I am skeptical that this would have been the *definition* of absolute value and would have expected it instead to have been an *identity* involving the absolute value.  Of course, one can show that (*given an appropriate definition of $\sqrt{~}$*) the definitions are equivalent, I find it far more natural to let absolute value of real numbers be defined as $|x|=\begin{cases}x&\text{if }x\geq 0\\ -x&\text{otherwise}\end{cases}$

Comment: @JMoravitz I agree

Comment: Please ask one question per question.

Comment: The conclusion $-\theta < \sin\theta < \theta$ needs to be viewed in context. It can only be true if $\theta$ is positive, because otherwise $-\theta \geq \theta.$